# Unit/Functional Tests Vs Validators

Tags: python-3.x, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I have recently started web development using Django. What confuses me the most that, why do we create tests for scenarios like "Check if password is provided", "Check if password is correct", "Check if a password is at least 8 characters long" etc. when we can do the same thing using validators in Django. Is there a specific advantage of using tests over validators? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing a big project and manually test all the functionalities to make sure there are NO bugs and then write tests for the entire thing and I guarantee you will find at least 5